# Getting a text respons using Fetch API and a PHP file

Tags: fetch-api

I am hitting a php file and the response returns a string. I can't find the documentation on how to deal with this.

From the google developer doc [google developer doc](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch), my fetch is simple

```
fetch('upvotes.php')
  .then(
    function(response) {
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
          response.status);
        return;
      }

      // Examine the text in the response
      response.json().then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  )
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
  });
```

And PHP

```
<?php
    function test(){
        return "This is a test";
    }
    echo test();
?>
```

This fails on the `response.json()` assumedly because I am returning just a string. If I log out just the response (attached screen shot) I get something I have no idea how to work with, and I cannot convert it. Where is my return value from the PHP here?

[image]

`response.json` causes the dreaded `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

How can the value from the PHP?

Comment: use `.text()` instead of `.json()`

Comment: That is the answer. Put it below and we'll wrap this up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP isn't returning JSON, it's just returning a string so use `.text()` instead.